# How can automatically assign all the prospects to a user in Pardot?

Tags: leads, user, import, assignment-rules, pardot

I want to import a list of prospects in a list in Pardot. import process is quiet easy. I just don't know how to assign all these users to a specific user during the import operation.
does anybody have any experience?

Answer (score 1):

I would choose to make use of an automation rule that assigns the prospect to a user once they are added to the list.